# Unknown SSH connections in lsof

Tags: ssh

Does this output mean this IP is connected to SSH?

```
root@ubuntu:/home/stg03# lsof -i
sshd      16782     root    3u  IPv4 59791433      0t0  TCP 192.168.3.237:ssh->**58.218.198.156:53245** (ESTABLISHED)
sshd      16783     sshd    3u  IPv4 59791433      0t0  TCP 192.168.3.237:ssh->**58.218.198.156:53245** (ESTABLISHED)
```

Because everytime this IP gets changed in the listener and it does not belong to me, Chinese IP.

```
sshd      16687     root    3u  IPv4 59787130      0t0  TCP 192.168.3.237:ssh->**221.194.47.205**:39660 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd      16688     sshd    3u  IPv4 59787130      0t0  TCP 192.168.3.237:ssh->**221.194.47.205**:39660 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Comment: I removed the second part because it is a different question (and impossible to answer with the bit of output you supplied)

Comment: Thank you, for the readers, I have changed the ssh passwords but the connectivity still established from those IPs.

Comment: I know that you are trying to figure out if your server is compromised, but this question is not actually about security. You are trying to interpret the output of a non-security commandline tool. If you lookup `lsof`'s man page, you will see that yes, an SSH connection has been `ESTABLISHED`

Comment: And, just because a TCP connection is established doesn't mean they have authenticated. Have you checked your auth logs?